# Find the course or heading of an object

Tags: gnss, heading

Im working with orientation using GPS + IMU, and before the actual implementation of the program, im working with simulation using a dataset that provides me some GPS data, such as latitude, longitude, elevation and bearing, with this information, is there any way to find the heading or the course information of the object? Like the one given by the nmea VTG packet.

Comment: "is there any way to find the heading or the course information of the object?" is not very clear. By 'orientation', do you mean 'TO' an object? Do you need to know the course 'between' 2 objects? Do you need to know the distances too? Many IMU's today have a magnetometer sensor on board to give you instantaneous heading of the unit. You need a simple course/distance calculation module for your dataset.

Comment: I need the orientation of an object with respect of magnetic north, i have found that with magnetometer data i can find this information.

Comment: Does that cover everything you had on your mind for your post?

Comment: Yes, im working with GPS + IMU fusion and the orientation and coordinate frame is my biggest problem now. The system dinamics and covariances matrix i already solved. I'm new in this topic so, i'm discovering how this things works, i have found Madgwick filters to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Knowing Lat/Lon, elevation, and bearing (and, presumably, distance) from a known reference point, the current track or heading could be anything.

It's like saying, if you know where I am, can you tell which way I'm facing (or walking)? Given one data point, you can't. Over time you might plot the points to work out the track, but that's your result, not given by the data *per-se.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will search for other dataset that give me the heading.

Comment: And of course be aware of the difference between heading and track, although it sounds like you are already.